# Extjs adding a column to a model

Tags: extjs

In my extjs column model, here is what i have:

```
new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
columns: [
{id:'msgId',hidden: false, dataIndex: 'msgId'}                  
]
```

Now, i wish to add another column to the model and that column will be a hyperlink with text : 'View Message Details' and on click should call a javascript function fnMessageDetails('msgId').

How to add this column to the model? Can I add a column with no `dataIndex` attribute?

Comment: Do you want to add it dynamicaly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I add a column with no dataIndex attribute?

Yes, it's ok if you use your own renderer or templatecolumn.

> How to add this column to the model?

You can use `renderer` config or `templatecolumn`. For example:

```
new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
  columns: [
    {id:'msgId',hidden: false, dataIndex: 'msgId'},
    {
        header: 'info',
        xtype: 'templatecolumn',
        tpl: '<a href="#">View Message Details</a>',
        listeners: {
            click: function(col, grid, row){
                fnMessageDetails(grid.store.getAt(row).get('msgId'));
                return false;
            }
        }
    } 
  ]
});
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/UZcT3/1/)